# ArcGIS Javascript API 4.14 Add attached image in custom popup template

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am using arcGIS Javascript API 4.14 webmap and I wanted to add an image to the custom popup template. When I enable it by adding the code,

```
FeatureLayer.capabilities.data.supportsAttachment = true;
```

my custom template styles are not working. I am accessing other layer properties such as,

```
address = feature.graphic.attributes.LOCATIONADDRESS;
```

Is there any way to access the image also in the popup?

Please suggest me a way to add the image url in the popup.

Here is the code used for popup 
map.js

```
// The custom script required to add for the new APIs
var dojoConfig = {
  has: {
    "esri-native-promise": true
  }
};

// The map classes and includes
require([
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/WebMap",
  "esri/widgets/Search",
  "esri/widgets/Zoom",
  "esri/widgets/Locate",
  "esri/popup/content/ImageMediaInfo"
], function(MapView, WebMap, Search, Zoom, Locate, ImageMediaInfo) {
  // The webmap declaration
  var webmap = new WebMap({
    portalItem: {
      id: "003dc702f34a44cd88001de7435e1f79"
    }
  });
  /* The map view, the webmapid assigned. The WebMap instance created */
  var view = new MapView({
    map: webmap,
    container: "map",
    center: [-95.9406, 41.26],
    zoom: 16,
    maxZoom: 21,
    minZoom: 13,
    basemap: "topo",
// remove the default zoom controlls
ui: {
  components: ["attribution"]
}


});

  webmap
    .load()
    .then(function() {

  return webmap.basemap.load();
})
.then(function() {
  /* Grab all the layers and load them */
  let allLayers = webmap.allLayers;
  console.log(allLayers);

  var promises = allLayers.map(function(layer) {
    return layer.load();
  });
  return Promise.all(promises.toArray());
})
.then(function(layers) {
  // webmap.removeAll();
  webmap.remove(layers[1]);
  webmap.remove(layers[2]);
  webmap.remove(layers[3]);
  webmap.remove(layers[4]);
  webmap.remove(layers[5]);

  webmap.remove(layers[6]);
  // webmap.remove(layers[7]);

  webmap.remove(layers[8]);
  webmap.remove(layers[9]);
  webmap.remove(layers[10]);
  webmap.remove(layers[11]);
  webmap.remove(layers[12]);

  var popupTemplate;

  // Sets the location of the popup to the center of the view

  // Position of the popup in relation to the selected feature.
  view.popup.alignment = "top-center";
  // To disable the collapse functionality
  view.popup.collapseEnabled = false;
  // A spinner appear at the pointer
  view.popup.spinnerEnabled = false;
  // To disable the dock (The popup will be appear in bottom or any corner of the window)
  view.popup.dockEnabled = false;
  // Disable the pagination
  view.popup.featureNavigationEnabled = false;
  // Popup template details, Keep only name and address in the popup and avoid all other details
  // view.popup.viewModel.actions.getItemAt(0).visible = false;

  // view.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false;
  view.popup.defaultPopupTemplateEnabled = false;

  view.popup.actionsMenuEnabled = false;

  view.on("click", function(event) {});

  for (let i = 2; i < layers.length; i++) {
    var template = {
      title: function() {
        return "Popup Headding";
      },
      content: function(feature) {
        // to enable the image in the popup
        // feature.graphic.layer.capabilities.attachment.supportsContentType = true;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var address = feature.graphic.attributes.Address;
        var facilityID = feature.graphic.attributes.FACILITYID;
        var numberofstalls = "";

        // Condition for showing the handicapped layers 6,7
        address =
          "<div class='onstreet_image'><img src=" +
          feature.graphic.attributes.IMAGE_URL +
          " /><a href=" +
          feature.graphic.attributes.IMAGE_URL +
          " target='_blank'>Photo</a></div>";
        div.innerHTML =
          '<div id="popup_address">' + address + "</div>" + numberofstalls;
        return div;
      },
      outFields: [
        "Name",
        "Address",
        "FACILITYID",
        "LOCATIONADDRESS",
        "LOCATIONNAME",
        "NUMEROFSTALLS",
        "IMAGE_URL"
      ]
    };
    layers[i].popupTemplate = template;
    // console.log(layers[i]);
  }

  // To close the popup when hit on esc button
  document.onkeyup = function(evt) {
    var key = evt.keyCode;
    if (key == 27) {
      view.popup.close();
    }
  };
})
.catch(function(error) {
  //   console.log(error);
});
});
```

index file

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />

<title>Load a basic WebMap - 4.14</title>

<style>
  html,
  body,
  #map {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script


src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```
.esri-popup__header-title {


color: #38466a !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.275rem !important;
  min-width: 180px;
  /* word-break: break-word !important;
  word-wrap: break-word !important; */
  word-break: normal !important;
}
.esri-popup__header-title:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* .esri-popup__content {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0 !important;
} */

#popupRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #229fd7;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* height: 90px; */
}

/* the plus symbol in the popup */
.right p {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
  font-size: xx-large !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* to remove the scroll bar in the popup content */
.esri-popup__content {
  height: 40px;
}
/* To make a fixed length of the popup */
.esri-view-width-xlarge .esri-popup__main-container {
  width: 250px !important;
}

/* To hide the footer area in arcGIS 4.14 */
.esri-popup__footer {
  display: none !important;
}
/* to remive the blue outline around the map */
.esri-view .esri-view-surface--inset-outline:focus::after {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the custom style to the question, in that way maybe the problem can be reproduce.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. My client added the image URL as a field name, so I have used the same instead of an attachment. Here my problem is the image in the popup is appearing anti-clockwise. How can we show the image in the popup in the proper direction?I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

"Supports attachements" means that the user has the ability to add images or documents which are stored in the geodatabase with a relationship class between the feature class and the table.  If the image you wish to add is actually an image attached to the record in the geodatabase, you can set the properties of the popup to display attachments using the [AttachmentsContent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-popup-content-AttachmentsContent.html) object.

If you want to display the attached image in some other way (which seems like you are re-inventing the wheel), then you need to use the [queryAttachments](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#queryAttachments) method and then use the [url from that](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-AttachmentInfo.html#url) in the popup ([see PopupTemplate with promise](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popuptemplate-promise/index.html) example).

If you are trying to add an image from somewhere else on the internet (which sounds closer to what you are trying to do), then you need to add a [ImageMediaInfo object](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-popup-content-ImageMediaInfo.html) to the Popuptemplate that you are defining.

Comment: I have created a web-map with layers and I have added images in the 'Add Pop-up media' section. I want to show the same image in the pop-up. I have customized the content part as I have to show the customized popup. When I add the image, the customization are missing. Please refer the code I have updated.

Comment: The code you included doesn't reference images anywhere, either through an img tag or the ImageMediaInfo object.  You have to use one of those two to add an image to your popup.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was getting the image in my popup even if I don't use the ImageMediaInfo but with "FeatureLayer.capabilities.data.supportsAttachment = true;". The issue I am facing is, when the image appears, all the custom style is disappearing and the default popup appears. The code I was added to make the custom popup provided above. Please help me to customize the code to keep the same custom popup.